# Why is array_walk with anonymous function providing different result than foreach?

Tags: php

PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.15

1st, starting values:

```
$value_array = array('0.000','2.530',8);
$op_value = 2;
```

Try this:

```
            foreach($value_array as &$source_value) {
                $source_value = $source_value + $op_value;
            }
```

And get $value_array == (2,4.53,10);

But if you run this:

```
            array_walk($value_array,function(&$source_value) {
                $source_value = $source_value + $op_value;
            });
```

You get $value_array == (0,2.53,8);

The first one gives the expected result, the second one doesn't. But it does do SOMEthing. The excess 0's ended up getting chopped off.

Why is this? I wanted to use array_walk but now have to use foreach.

Comment: Where is $op_value coming from? - It's not available in the callback.

Comment: That must be the answer. I have to add it as the second parameter to `array_walk`, don't I? oops.

Comment: Not as the second parameter to `array_walk`, but as one of the arguments to your `function()` - or use `use` as @Barmar mentions

Comment: ubuntu 4.15? time for an update? ;)

Comment: @JordanArseno - that's not the OS version in the php version string, that's the ubuntu specific revision for PHP

Comment: Haha yeah it's not 4.15. I'm using Lucid - 10.04.4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `use` declaration to access the outside variable:

```
        array_walk($value_array,function(&$source_value) use ($op_value) {
            $source_value = $source_value + $op_value;
        });
```

or if it's a global you can do:

```
        array_walk($value_array,function(&$source_value) {
            global $op_value;
            $source_value = $source_value + $op_value;
        });
```

Comment: This code is inside of a class method. $op_value is also inside of it. global will still work?

Comment: No, global is only for global variables. For local variables that must be captured in a closure, you have to use `use`.

Comment: Thanks, glad you covered 2 solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can also use the third parameter of `array_walk` to specify an [extra parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to pass to the callback function.

```php
array_walk($value_array, function(&$source_value, $key, $extra_param) { // <--- (2) and use here
    $source_value = $source_value + $extra_param;
}, $op_value); // <--- (1) pass it here
```